# How to use TEMENOS API in PHP?

Tags: api

How to use TEMENOS API in PHP:
Please anyone help me about using of temenos api in php.

TEMENOS API Url: 1. http://developer.dev.temenos.cloud/apis/index.html
                 2. https://developer.temenos.com/index.php/community/build-detail-2/

Answer (score 1):

The same way you use any other API from PHP! The Temenos API is just providing you JSON rest web service over http and this is what you should code in PHP.

I guess what you should be asking is: how to consume Rest Web Service from PHP. Some exampls from web:

https://www.allphptricks.com/create-and-consume-simple-rest-api-in-php/

So, you probably need to use curl in PHP:

```
$url = "https://api.temenos.com/api/v1.0.0/holdings/PSD2/accounts/" . $account_id;

$client = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($client);

$result = json_decode($response);
```